# How do you tell if you're overly dependent on libraries?

Tags: architecture, implementation

I once did some work for a rails shop. It seemed that every other day, the lead dev would add a new gem to the project.

This caused me to wonder about the best practice when deciding to use a library or not. I'm definitely of the opinion that you shouldn't reinvent the wheel, but something just feels wrong about including, say an entire twitter library just for parsing feeds.

What are some best practices around developing with libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid Not Invented Here Syndrome -- if there is a library for it, use it. 
But also do not be afraid to stop using a library if it sucks.  If you are spending way to much time working around moronic problems/limitations of a library which can be rewritten in reasonable amount of time (say, 1 week to 1 month depending on how close it's functionality is to your products core competency) it might be time to replace the library with something which will work better for you.
Of course take my week-month estimate as a superficially guess, I've seen situations where it was a good idea to invest 2 man years into a library rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to state library reuse "good habits" in a measurable way.  But I would suggest:

- don't use a new library to accomplish what you could have reasonably achieved with the base libraries of your chosen tech stack.
- don't use a new library if you are using a tiny fraction of the capabilities it offers.
- don't use a new library if it is, well, new.  The exception being the library is something you've been desparately needing for months and your project team have all been waiting for this new library to "save" them.  Otherwise, you can probably wait for "version 2 or 3" of this "new" library before you incorporate it.
- You already know what makes a new library "good."  But don't use a new library if you have not yet evaluated what makes it "bad".
- don't use a new library if you havn't considered the training and training schedule necessary to bring the dev team up-to-speed on the new tech.

Anyone could poke holes in the suggestions I've made above, but generally it is true that taking on new dependencies in your project code can invite a lot of risk.  Doing it often is an anti-pattern in my book.  I suggest your team should all give a listen to "[Simplicity: the way of the unusual architect](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simplicity-Architect)".